# How do I clear the terminal using Bash terminal on Windows 10 with VScode

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, terminal

I tried mapping cntrl+k without success. When I do a clear it takes me to the top of the terminal and doesn't clear.

Comment: Try the “clear” command? YMMV.

Comment: In most terminals when the `clear` command is used, it just clears the console view and scrolls you to the top.   The reason being is to still provide you with "scroll-back" in case you needed to go back over your history.

Comment: Maybe ^L (Ctrl-L)?